# Scala Await a expired Future doesn't see TimeoutException

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I'm trying to wrap Kafka's callback-y producer **send** API as a Future. i.e.:

```
def sendFuture[K, V](p: KafkaProducer[K, V], rec: ProducerRecord[K, V]): Future[RecordMetadata] = {
  val promise = Promise[RecordMetadata]()
  p.send(rec, new Callback {
    override def onCompletion(metadata: RecordMetadata, exception: Exception): Unit = {
      if (metadata != null) {
        promise.complete(Success(metadata))
      } else {
        promise.complete(Failure(exception))
      }
    }
  })
  promise.future
}
```

I deliberately disable the Kafka broker, so that a producer would for a configured time(5000 ms) keep connecting.
In my test, I only Await for 2 seconds and expect to see a **TimeoutException** thrown.

```
"a producer can't connect to the broker, we " should {
  "see timeout when sending messages" in withProducer { p: KafkaProducer[String, String] =>
    val rec = new ProducerRecord[String, String](TEST_TOPIC, "testKey", "testValue")
    val f = sendFuture(p, rec)

    log.info(">> sent and we wait for at most 1 second...")
    intercept[TimeoutException] {
      Await.ready(f, 2 seconds)
    }
    log.info(">> TimeoutException intercepted")
  }
}
```

I would expect Await waits "*on parallel*" and then fires **TimeoutException**.
Unfortunately, my test would fail.
It seems that Await, despite the 2-second bound, always waits until the Future is **completed** with a failure by the **send's callback**.
I don't quite see the reason.

I think this has more to do with implementation details of Kafka because
I only observe this behaviour when the Future is completed by Kafka **send's callback**.
That is, replacing `sendFuture` by `dummyFuture` passes the test:

```
def dummyFuture(): Future[Boolean] = {

  val promise = Promise[Boolean]()
  val thread = new Thread(new Runnable {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      promise.complete(Success(true))
    }
  })
  thread.start()
  promise.future
}
```

Thanks for any help.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/cfchou/c3fca4385b03792553e9)

[Kafka Producer API](http://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord,%20org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback))

Comment: Have you verified that it really waits for longer than 2 seconds, or is it just your assumption  that `.send` would take longer?

Comment: Thanks @Dima. Follow your advice, I found I was wrong to assume that `send` returns immediately while it's still trying to connect. It's asynchronous after the connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

I found I was wrong to assume that `send` returns immediately while it's still trying to connect. Await isn't timeout because it starts **after** `send` has reached configured timeout and completed the future with a failure.